# I can't figure out why this ds_data_grid is not being created before being called

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-language, game-maker-studio-2

I've been looking at my code for 2 hours now doing everything I can think of and this is the error I'm getting: https://pastebin.com/ga6CaL0w)

```
___________________________________________
############################################################################################
FATAL ERROR in
action number 1
of  Step Event0
for object hiveEngine:

Variable hiveEngine.<unknown variable>(100010, -2147483648) not set before reading it.
 at gml_Script_instance_create_hive (line 13) -        maxHoney = hiveEngine.ds_hive_types[# 0, hiveType]
############################################################################################
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
stack frame is
gml_Script_instance_create_hive (line 13)
called from - gml_Object_hiveEngine_Step_0 (line 27) -        instance_create_hive(mouse_x,mouse_y,hiveTypes.langstroth);
```

It seems that the ds/grid isn't being created...here is my script for creating a new instance hive (https://pastebin.com/mXL3jard), my code for creating the initial grid (https://pastebin.com/1Zuqdfj2) and this is the entire step event from the hiveEngine object (https://pastebin.com/Z9V4bE8D).

I'm walking away from this before I completely lose my mind.﻿

Answer (score 0):

changes

```
var inst = instance_create_layer (argument0, argument1, "Instances", obj_hive)
```

by

```
inst = instance_create_layer (argument0, argument1, "Instances", obj_hive)
```

and should work

- If it does not work, avoid the use of so many shorteners and the script because you are making a web, use the codes directly
  and you see `a = b = c = e = f`, place front`a = f`.
- the information you share in the documents is incomplete to understand your code